# Как проверить слово на соответствие массиву (JS)?

Tags: javascript, массивы, indexof

Дан массив из элементов [test, test1, test2, a, b, c]. Необходимо проверить, если введенное в текстовое поле слово, состоит из элементов массива (например, ввели слово "test1test2" или "cab"), то вывести сообщение "слово принадлежит массиву"

```js
var arr = ['test', 'test1', 'test2', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
array.innerHTML = arr;

function wordArray(){
    var x = document.getElementById('newArray');
    if(arr.indexOf(document.getElimentById("wordCheck").value) == 1){
        alert("Слово "+ document.getElementById("wordCheck").value + "принадлежит массиву");
    } else {
        alert("Слово " + document.getElementById("wordCheck").value + "не принадлежит массиву");
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
<div id="newArray"></div>
<div class="checkWord">
    <h2>Проверка слова на соответствие заданному алфавиту</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="inputWord">
        <input type="button" value="Проверить" onclick="wordArray()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: И что? В чем вопрос? Что не устраивает в приведенном коде? Вы пробовали нажать кнопку "Выполнить код"?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ['test', 'test1', 'test2', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
const str = 'test1a';

check(arr, str);

function check(arr, str) {
  const newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  let dpStr = str.slice();
  newArr.forEach(value => dpStr = dpStr.replace(value, ""));
  if (!dpStr) {
    return console.log('Соотвествует');
  }
  return console.log('Не соотвествует');
}
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Тоже были мысли с сортировкой по длине, но что-то отбросил.

Comment: можете объяснить  arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length); ?